# Can't assign a variable immediately from subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to retrieve one row from database and show this information on my page.

The problem is that subscribe is async so it's not executed immediately therefore I can't access the data from the start.
This is the error shown when I execute the code:

[image]

But this attribute is actually shown on a page since got received eventually. That's how I understand that. I was trying to get rid of this problem for hours and I just can't figure it out.  How can I suppress these errors on my browser due to late arrival of data from database?

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="img-text">
    <div class="img-left">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/person.png">
    </div>
    <div class="img-right">
      <b>Customer name: </b> {{order.customerName}}<br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

order-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OrdersService } from '../orders.service';
import { Order } from '../order';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-details',
  templateUrl: './order-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-details.component.scss'],
  providers: [OrdersService]
})
export class OrderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() order: Order;

  constructor(private _ordersService: OrdersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrder();
    console.log(this.order);
  }

  getOrder(): any {
    this._ordersService.getOrder(1).subscribe(order => this.order = order);
  }
```

Comment: You can use `ngIf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to make sure the data can be accessed; otherwise you'll try to read from an undefined property. There are a few ways to do this:

```
<b>Customer name: </b> {{order?.customerName}}<br>
```

This will still display `Customer name:` with nothing. Instead you may want to use `ngIf` with `else` to show a loading indicator or something like that.

```
<div class="img-right" *ngIf="order$ | async as order; else loading">
  <b>Customer name: </b> {{order.customerName}}<br>
</div>
<div #loading>Loading...</div>
```

Note that `order` probably shouldn't be an input. You will need an `order$` property:

```
order$ = this._ordersService.getOrder(1);
```

The `| async` takes care of the subscribe and unsubscribe for you.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation was spot on. Does the ? sign just makes the browser ignore the errors about this particular attribute about async data display? Or does it have any other uses?

Comment: This is essentially the same as `(order ? order : {}).customerName`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?` operator: `order?.customerName`

Comment: Thanks. That solved it! Could you please explain the use of this in Angular? I am quite new to this :)

Comment: This operator stops evaluating when object before `?` is null/undefined and avoid to throw exception

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to initialize an empty order in the constructor:

```
constructor(private _ordersService: OrdersService) {
    this.order = {};
 }
```